# Business Statistics, Numerical Discrete/Continuous

Tags: statistics

We have an online quiz and my Prof is asking the question:

The time in hours spend exercising per week is what kind of a variable?
a) Quantitative
b) Numerical Discrete
c) Numerical Continuous

I know it is not Quantitative, but what I simply cannot understand is why the "right answer" (for him at least is) Numerical Continuous. Because there is only a certain amount of hours you can exercise in a week right? I can not workout for 3000 hours in one week can I? So am I wrong or is he?

Comment: What's a Quantitative Variable?  Just one that is measured using numbers?  (as opposed to a descriptive parameter like eye color or something).  I mean, I would have said that both $a$ and $c$ were good answers.

Comment: @lulu Torben Are we sure that "quantitative" wasn't "qualitative"? In my experience, you'd get asked whether some data can be represented by a number or by a descriptor in this kind of thing.

Comment: @Jam  Yes, that's exactly my question.  A person's height is a Quantitative Variable.  Their favorite music is a Qualitative Variable.

Comment: @lulu I know, I was wondering if Torben got the words mixed up :)

Answer (score 1):

The difference between a discrete and a continuous variable is essentially whether it makes sense to have half a unit of something. It doesn't make sense to count half a house or half a person, so these things are discrete. But can we count half an hour? Or $0.3$ hours?

You're right that there is a limit on the amount of time in a week but that doesn't affect whether the variable is discrete or continuous. You can have both continuous and discrete variables in certain limits.